# Windows Service performing work on a timer with graceful shutdown

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a Windows Service that executes a job on a timer and has graceful shutdown.  I've used various questions/answers on here to come up with the code below.  It works but I want to make sure it's the most correct and elegant solution.  And I have specific questions too (after code).

This is the main service class.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace MyService
{

    public class MyService : ServiceBase
    {

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        System.Timers.Timer serviceTimer;
        Task workTask;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                Run(new MyService());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            serviceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
            serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(serviceTimer_Elapsed);
            serviceTimer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                serviceTimer.Stop();
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

                if (workTask != null)
                {
                    workTask.Wait(10000);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                serviceTimer.Dispose();
                serviceTimer = null;

                cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                cancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
        }

        private void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            serviceTimer.Stop();

            workTask = Task.Run(() => StartWorkMethod()).ContinueWith(WorkCompleted);
        }

        private void WorkCompleted(Task completedTask)
        {
            workTask = null;

            serviceTimer.Start();
        }

        private void StartWorkMethod()
        {
            Work work = new Work(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            work.StartWork();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the class that performs the (currently simulated) work.

```
using System.Threading;

namespace MyService
{

    public class Work
    {

        CancellationToken cancellationToken;

        public Work(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        }

        public void StartWork()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The service works and runs all tasks without blocking the handler threads.  If the service is stopped, the OnStop method will wait for the task's current block of work to complete for a certain period of time before stopping anyways (thanks Ian of Oz!).

Here are my specific questions:

1. To prevent the service from stopping immediately and waiting for the current block to complete, I am using the `working` variable and a while loop to wait for the `Work` class to complete and the bool to be set to `false`.  Is this the best way to handle this?  Already answered by Ian of Oz.
2. I also want to have a "feature" where if the current block is taking too long to complete, the `OnStop` method will only wait a certain amount of time before exiting anyways.  What is the best way to implement that?  Already answerd by Ian of Oz.
3. I've tried to make sure I handle all threading issues with my code.  Is there anything I missed or that might cause trouble later with this implementation?

Also some notes to avoid any confusion:

- Service install code is not included, I am using an installer to install the service.
- The timer controls the time between executions so that there aren't overlapping executions if the previous execution takes longer; this is why the timer stops before starting the work and restarts after.
- I've seen where the `Main` method is sometimes placed in it's own file, but mostly where the executable is also the installer; in this case it would only simplify this file by the `Main` method itself.

Edited to incorporate suggestion from Ian of Oz.

Comment: Could you hang onto the Task you create in serviceTimer_Elapsed and then add a call to Task.Wait(milliseconds) after your call cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() ?

Comment: @IanofOz, thanks!  I tested that and it worked.  I thought I would have to add a timer of some kind in addition to my boolean that was tracking if work was happening.  But Task.Wait replaced the boolean and took care of the waiting for x time part too.  Awesome suggestion!

Comment: Glad the Task idea worked @BenderIsGreat. Another approach you can look at is actually delaying the stop of your service if you need to. By default you have 20 seconds (or at least it used to be, checking on my Windows 8 machine it seems the default is now 5 seconds). This is controlled by a registry entry at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout.

Comment: Sorry, got cut off there... if you need more time (eg for you Task to finish), you can call RequestAditionalTime on ServiceBase to delay the finishing of the service. 
You could also use the WaitToKillServiceTimeout value for a less-hardcoded value for your Task.Wait timeout value.